# Error message in package oddsratio: "R: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , pred, value = NULL) : duplicate subscripts for columns"

Tags: r

I have a data frame, `newdata`, with many rows and columns. I am only trying to study the effect size of two variables, `DHHGAGE` and `ADL_01`, on the predictor variable, `INJG11A`. For now, I want to calculate the odds ratio for `model_1` in RStudio. This is my code:

```
model_1 <- newdata$INJG11A ~ newdata$DHHGAGE + newdata$ADL_01

library(oddsratio)
or_gam(data = newdata, model = model_1, pred = newdata$INJG11A)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in \`[<-.data.frame\`(\`\*tmp\*`, , pred, value = NULL) : 
  duplicate subscripts for columns
```

Can anyone help? Please note this question is not about whether the odds ratio is the right statistic to compute in this case, but rather how it works in R.

Comment: Not familiar with package, but examples quote the `pred` param -- so, maybe it should be `'newdata$INJG11A'`

Answer (score 1):

Read the help page. The `pred`-parameter is supposed to be a character value that is the name of the desired predictor. The 'INJG11A' variable is not the predictor; it is the outcome variable in the model you specified. Furthermore, models should never have the dataset name but rather only the unquoted variables:

So instead try:

```
model_1 <-INJG11A ~ DHHGAGE + ADL_01

or_gam(data = newdata, model = model_1, pred = 'DHHGAGE')
```

Actually, that will also probably fail because the `or_gam` function's default for `values` is NULL and that parameter is also needed. Needs to be two numeric values, with the calculated result being the odds ratio for the second versus the first as values for the pred-variable. There is a vignette for the package and you should spend some time with it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between an outcome variable and predictor. This worked: 
model_1 <- glm(INJG11A ~ DHHGAGE, data = mydata)
library(oddsratio)
or_gam(data = newdata, model = model_1, pred = 'DHHGAGE', values = c(1,2))