# Error 'duplicate subscripts for columns' on using CreateTableOne

Tags: r, create-table

I was trying to do `CreateTableOne` from `tableone` package for my dataset called m.dataaaaaa using the following code:

```
CreateTableOne(vars =Vars,strata = "ejecfraclesstha40_gps",  factorVars =Catvars, data = m.dataaaaaa,  test = T)
```

But I got the following error :

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(x, i, value = value) :    duplicate
>   subscripts for columns In addition: Warning message: In
>   ModuleReturnVarsExist(vars, data) :   The data frame does not have:
>   ejecfraclesstha40  Dropped

structure of the data is shown below as it is a big database

str(m.dataaaaaa)

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  194 obs. of  203 variables:
 $ ejecfraclesstha40_gps                       : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ Serial.ID                                   : num  2 3 4 7 10 14 17 20 23 24 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F4.0"
 $ Serial.ID_matched.EF.cohort.Ivan1.to.2      : num  2 NA 4 NA NA NA 17 20 23 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.0"
 $ ps..matched.EF.cohort.Ivan1.to.2            : num  0.138 NA 0.19 NA NA NA 0.176 0.286 0.152 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.3"
 $ psweight1.to.2                              : num  1 NA 1 NA NA NA 1 1 1 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
 $ matched_ID1.to.2                            : num  483 NA 763 NA NA NA 180 176 239 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
 $ matched_cases_in_control1.to.2              : num  2 NA 2 NA NA NA 2 2 2 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
 $ ejecfrac_4gps                               : num  1 3 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num  1 2 3 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "EF<35%" "EF=35 - <40%" "EF=40 - <=50" "EF>50%"
 $ ejecfrac_4gps30                             : num  1 4 1 3 3 4 1 1 1 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num  1 2 3 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "EF<=30%" "EF>30 - 39%" "EF=40 - 49%" "EF>=50%"
 $ renisch                                     : num  29 31 23 18 48 19 10 29 17 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "renal + visceral ischemic time"
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F3.0"
  ..- attr(*, "display_width")= int 12
 $ totxct                                      : num  46 31 55 46 48 19 54 29 17 37 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "total cross-clamp time"
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F4.0"
  ..- attr(*, "display_width")= int 12
```

The original database was read from spss into r.
My main problem is with this error :

> Error in [<-.data.frame(x, i, value = value) : duplicate subscripts for columns

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From tableone package

Comment: @MrFlick Any idea on this question based on your prior answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792471/i-find-this-error-message-when-im-using-xml-in-r)

Comment: @42- Any idea on this question based on your prior answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131090/error-message-in-package-oddsratio-r-error-in-data-frametmp-pre)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue resolved by converting the categorical variables that I listed under the `factorVars` parameter from numeric to factor via `as.factor`.